# Android programmatically added views not showing in UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new to Java/Android, and probably trying to run before I can walk, but I have had some success starting on a version of the old 'Mastermind' code guessing game. My current stumbling block is that having entered my first guess of the code and generated the score for this guess, I want to present a new row of 'holes' ready to accept my next guess (the first set of holes is static in my `activity_main.xml` file). I have a LinearLayout (vertical orientation) called `guesses` to hold the rows of holes, and each row of holes is a LinearLayout (horizontal orientation) containing a TextView, to indicate which guess number this is, and a number of ImageViews for the empty guess holes and score holes.

I have written code to get the `guesses` Layout as the parent layout, create a new horizontal LinearLayout and use `addView` to add this into the `guesses` layout. I then switch my 'parent' layout to point to the new horizontal LinearLayout I've just created and create the various other TextView and ImageView items and add these to this new horizontal LinearLayout.

This code all runs without any errors. I just don't see any of my new layouts in the UI. What have I missed?

Extract of the code so far:

```
parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.guesses);
LinearLayout guessLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
guessLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        getResources().getIdentifier("@dimens/guessLayoutHeight", null, getPackageName()));
int pxMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        getResources().getIdentifier("@dimens/guessLayoutMargin", null, getPackageName()),
                        getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
layoutParams.setMargins(pxMargin, 0, pxMargin, 0);
guessLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
guessLayout.setId(guessNumber*10);
parentLayout.addView(guessLayout);

// Add the Guess# label
parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(guessNumber*10);
TextView guessLabel = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 11);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
guessLabel.setText("Guess " + guessNumber);
guessLabel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
guessLabel.setId(guessNumber*100);
parentLayout.addView(guessLabel);

// Add the guess positions
ImageView guessPosition;
pxMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
for (int i = 1 ; i <=4 ; i++ ) {
    guessPosition = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 6);
    if (i == 1) {
        layoutParams.setMarginStart(pxMargin);
    } else {
        layoutParams.setMarginStart(0);
    }
    guessPosition.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    guessPosition.setId(guessNumber*10 + i);

    guessPosition.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/blank_guess", null, getPackageName()));
    guessPosition.setTag("blank_guess");
    guessPosition.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    parentLayout.addView(guessPosition);
}
```

[Edit - the following additional question can be ignored. It's been answered]
This code is in the onClickListener for my `Score` Button. The other thing I want to do, having created the new ImageView items for my guess holes, is call `setOnDragListener` to use a listener that I've defined in the enclosing `onCreate` method of `MainActivity.java`. Is it possible to reference this listener from within another listener's code? I have the following declaration at the Class level:

```
ImageView guess1 = null;
```

...and what I was hoping to do was something like

```
guess1 = findViewById(guessNumber*10 + 1);
guess1.setOnDragListener(MainActivity.this.guessDragListener);
```

but it's telling me it can't resolve symbol `guessDragListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question: I'm not sure i understood it properly. Do you want to use the same OnDragListener for multiple Views? If so, try this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
View view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
View.OnDragListener onDragListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     onDragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    view.setOnDragListener(onDragListener);
    doStuff();
}

void doStuff(){
    view2.setOnDragListener(onDragListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I needed was to move the declaration of the listener up to the Class level instead of having it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: For your other problem, take a look at the 'Layout Inspector'. Its under 'Tools'. Maybe the views show up there.

Comment: Cool! So for the original objects (defined in `activity_main.xml`) they show up as `AppCompatTextView` and `AppCompatImageView`, whereas the ones I've added programmatically are showing as `TextView` and `ImageView`. So they _are_ there, I just can't see them in the UI. Do I have to do something to refresh the screen to make these new objects show? Or do I need to be adding them as the `AppCompat...` versions instead (if so, then how)?

Comment: After using the Layout Inspector, I've discovered that it's all to do with how I'm converting units for the various dimensions - where I use `pxMargin = ...`. In my `dimens.xml` everything is defined in dp, but I thought that all the methods for setting heights, margins etc were expecting pixels, so I need to convert. I tried hard-coding the dimensions of my new objects the same as my original static objects, and stuff has miraculously started appearing. I've just got to work out now how to correctly do the conversions from dp to px.

Comment: I'm using this: int i = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics())); You might not need the Math.round and i think you could even swap COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP with COMPLEX_UNIT_PX if you want to go vice versa.

Comment: I went with `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.name);` - seems to do the job. Thaks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same view 4 times. The variable is not recreated but is changing its reference

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <=4 ; i++ )
ImageView guessPosition = new ImageView(MainActivity.this)
...
```

And the whole thing for the margins can be reduced to

```
int margin = getResources().getDimens(R.dimens.name)
```

That value is on the needed DPs

Comment: Adding the same view 4 times - yes, that's because I want 4 of them. Thanks for the pointer about `R.dimen.name` though - that's tidied up my code a little.